# How to enable git annotations in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

This is a silly problem, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to enable git annotations within PhpStorm. Normally you can just right click the line number gutter and select `Annotate` which displays information about who committed that code, when it was committed, and links to the commit on github. However, when I right click, the `Annotate` button is gray and not clickable.

[image: Gray annotate button]

I do have both git and github set up within my PhpStorm preferences:

[image: git setup][image: github setup]

There's probably another setting in there somewhere, but I've been looking and I can't find it.

Anybody know how to get those git annotations working?

Comment: Possibly stupid question but ... did you actually set the VCS root in this project (the `Version Control` settings page)? Can you actually commit etc using PhpStorm's VCS integration?

Comment: Haha, yep, that's what caused it. The VCS wasn't registered for that particular subproject. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**Version Control Integration:**

1. Click on VCS in Menu Bar
2. Click Enable Version Control Integration...

[image]

3. Select Git from Drop-down and then press OK Button.

[image]

**Remove Version Control Integration:**

1. Go to the Settings (Alt+Ctrl+S in windows).
2. At Version Control you can remove Integrated VCS.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer, couldn't for the life of me find it.