# Close all but unmodified files

Tags: phpstorm

So according to this link:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/closing-files-in-the-editor.html

There should be 'Close all but unmodified' option, when I right click, on an open file tab. I have git integrated, but I do not have this option. Is there some extra step I am not aware of?

Comment: As I stated in my question, I do have it integrated, but it is still not there :)

Comment: LazyOne's comment was correct. You need to visit `Window` menu and then open the `editor tabs` submenu. It's not a right-click option.

Comment: *"I do have it integrated"* proofs please. Sorry to say ..  but just less than 1 week ago I've seen a question from a person who uses this tool for quite some time .. and this time he simply forgot to enable VCS integration (did not do it till the end for some reason and though it was setup OK) -- http://stackoverflow.com/q/38618843/783119. It may happen here as well.

Comment: @LazyOne even if the integration is not set up correctly, your previous comment that it's not a *right click* option but a **file menu option** still stands, I thought.

Comment: @Martin You are correct .. but only partially. Usually (at least in most cases) IDE does not simply show unavailable actions in context menus while still have them visible (although disabled) in main menu. So I've double checked the actual context menu for editor tab (trough customisation option) .. and that action is there (part of "Editor Close Actions" group). Therefore *I believe* that if that action will be enabled/working trough `Menu | Window | Editor Tabs` menu then it *should be available* in context menu as well. At least this is my current understanding.

Comment: @LazyOne, I do have it integrated. Project root and everything is set. Ok.. I found it under `Menu | Window | Editor Tabs`. Why the hell all the other options available through right click, and this one is buried? Arguably the most useful one :)

Comment: @galdikas Well ... I believe it *should be* there (as per my previous comment). But if it's not available in context menu -- `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Menus and Toolbars` -- you can edit that menu and add that action there for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the Clarification, @LazyOne. That's a good explanation.